# How to get the Google Map based on Latitude on Longitude?

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

I want to display Google map in my web page based on longitude and latitude. First user want to enter longitude and latitude in two text box's. Then click submit button I have to display appropriate location in Google map.And also I want to show the weather report on it.How to do that? Thank You.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

this is the javascript to display google map by passing your longitude and latitude.

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }

    function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;


</script>
```

Comment: I tired pasting the above code onto my page and nothing is showing. Do I need extra code to make this work?

Comment: you need <div="map_canvas"></div> some where

Comment: Actually you need:  <div id="map_canvas"></div>

Answer (score 105):

Create a URI like this one:

https://maps.google.com/?q=[lat],[long]

For example:

https://maps.google.com/?q=-37.866963,144.980615

or, if you are using the javascript API

```
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(0,0))
```

This, and other helpful info comes from here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/?csw=1#Map

Comment: You can also get a static image of that location using the Static Maps API -- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ (e.g. http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-37.866963,144.980615&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false)

Comment: Or embed a scrollable JS map using the JS API -- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Comment: how to pass latitude and longtitude to javascript to display google map instead of iframe?

Answer (score 3):

Have you gone through google's geocoding api. The following link shall help you get started:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests

Answer (score 3):

Firstly add a div with id.

```
<div id="my_map_add" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function my_map_add() {
var myMapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(28.5383866, 77.34916609);
var myMapProp = {center:myMapCenter, zoom:12, scrollwheel:false, draggable:false, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("my_map_add"),myMapProp);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myMapCenter});
marker.setMap(map);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your_key&callback=my_map_add"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        //echo hiii;

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(8.5241, 76.9366),
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
        downloadUrl('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('package');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
                var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
                // var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
                // var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
                // var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
                // var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                // var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('latitude')),
                    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('longitude'))
                );

                var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
                var strong = document.createElement('strong');
                strong.textContent = name
                infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
                infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                var text = document.createElement('text');
                text.textContent = address
                infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
                var package = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    label: icon.label
                });

                package.addListener('click', function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                    infoWindow.open(map, package);
                });
            });
        });
    }


    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }
```

Comment: Is this correct for map integration through database